# How to change the product when user clicks color variant - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am working on some fashion website with Woo-commerce and wordpress. I want to change the product Like (Same product in Red, Same product in Blue) while user clicks color variant, How can I do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting your product type to variable product and add color attribute there from Add attributes to use for variations.

After adding color variation you can add multiple products there for an individual color option with different properties. You can do it from the variation tab.

For more information, you can see [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) tutorial.

Follow this tutorial step by step. This is the WooCommerece default functionality so You don't need to add any code or plugin for that.

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks.